# Force password submit on Google even when the user is already connected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm using https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 on a project.

I want to force the password re-submission every time a user tries to login through a Google OAuth2 roundtrip.
The problem is that if the account is already connected, it won't ask the user to type the password again.

I've tried to change the `prompt` option to `consent`, as I thought this was the way to achieve this desired behaviour, but it didn't work: it asks for the password *only* when the user is not yet connected (authenticated) in the Google account.

Is there a way to force the password resubmission on Google every time, regardless of whether it is already authenticated or not?

Thank you!

---

###### My current configurtion

```rb
  provider(
    :google_oauth2,
    ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
    ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    access_type: 'online',
    redirect_uri: "#{ENV.fetch('MY_HOST')}/auth/google_oauth2/callback",
    scope: 'email',
    prompt: 'select_account consent',
    image_aspect_ratio: 'square',
    image_size: 50
  )
```